# Using Haskell QuickCheck to test a TCP port validator

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am trying to use QuickCheck (for the first time) to test a function that validates TCP port numbers:

```hs
validatePort :: Int -> Either String Int
validatePort port =
  if port > 0 && port <= 65535
    then Right port
    else Left "Port must be between 1 and 65535 inclusive"
```

I wrote an instance of Arbitrary like this:

```hs
instance Arbitrary Int where
  arbitrary = choose (1, 65535)
```

but I'm not sure how to write the test property.

Comment: you should give some invalid ports as an input too to check the else branch (check out: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/testing-and-quality-assurance.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, first:   `import Test.QuickCheck` which already defines Arbitrary instance for Int

Then write a property:

```
prop_validate_port port = 
  if   port > 0 && port <= 65535
  then validatePort port == Right port
  else validatePort port == Left "Port must be between 1 and 65535 inclusive"
```

And run the test:

```
>quickCheck prop_validate_port
>+++ OK. passed 100 tests.
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that worked. At least, I think the test is running :-). I am using Hspec and not getting any errors. BTW, I am having a blast with Hspec and writing Haskell tests.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addendum to jev's answer, you can also enjoy a loosely-coupled testing framework by using custom `Gen`s:

```
validPorts :: Gen Int
validPorts = choose (1, 65535)

invalidPorts :: Gen Int
invalidPorts = oneof [choose (minBound, 0), choose (65536, maxBound)]

prop_validatePortValidatesValidPorts = 
  forAll validPorts (\port -> validatePort port == Right port)

prop_validatePortDoesNotValidateInvalidPorts =
  forAll invalidPorts (\port -> validatePort port == Left "...")
```